# Recover all files from recycle bin via commandline?

Tags: windows, command-line

Followed a nice article on Microsoft support forums on how can I fix failing windows update which involved to remove softwaredistributions and catroot folders then reboot.

I did that (moved them to recycle bin) but now computer is unable to boot no matter what I try.

**How can I restore all files from the recycle bin via command line to their original place?**

Comment: Recycle bin path is C:\$Recycle.Bin\<Your SID>.  You can try to copy files with something like `xcopy /E /H C:\$Recycle.Bin\<Your SID>\<Your directory>  C:\<Your target path>\ `

Comment: I myself suggest that you will fail in your endeavor.  If this were me?  I would use another windows pc to create a USB stick via the media creation tool.  Then use that usb stick to repair/install windows (keeping all files).  https://www.wintips.org/repair-windows-10-with-in-place-upgrade/